# Como mantengo datos con get y set que traigo desde bd

Tags: vb.net

primera vez que escribo. 
(Debo trabajar con vb.net y mysql)
Tengo que hacer un proyecto y necesito que cuando el usuario se loguea, mantenga los datos en el siguiente form. Ejemplo, me logueo con un usuario desde el form login, los datos son correctos y me deja entrar a otro form que sería el principal. El problema que tengo es que, al loguearse me muestra los datos que traigo desde la bd en un msg box pero luego en el siguiente form no los mantiene.
Había hecho un modulo y estaba todo en publico, lo cual me funcionaba.

```
Module ModuloUsuarios
    Public documento As Integer
    Public idusuario As Integer
    Public nombre As String
    Public apellido As String
    Public nivelusuario As String
End Module
```

Pero me dijeron que debía hacerlo por clase. Lo que tengo hasta ahora es esto:

```
Public Class sesionUsuario
    'Documento del usuario
    Private Documento_Usuario As Integer
    Public Property obtenerDocumento() As Integer
        Get
            Return Documento_Usuario
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Documento_Usuario = value
        End Set
    End Property
    'Tipo de usuario (Nivel identificador)
    Private id_Usuario As Integer
    Public Property obtenerIdUsuario() As Integer
        Get
            Return id_Usuario
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            id_Usuario = value
        End Set
    End Property
    'Nombre de Usuario
    Private Nombre_Usuario As String
    Public Property obtenerNombre() As String
        Get
            Return Nombre_Usuario
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Nombre_Usuario = value
        End Set
    End Property
    'Apellido de Usuario
    Private Apellido_Usuario As String
    Public Property obtenerApellido() As String
        Get
            Return Apellido_Usuario
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Apellido_Usuario = value
        End Set
    End Property
    'Estado del usuario (Si se encuentra activo o Inactivo)
    Private Estado_Usuario As String
    Public Property obtenerEstado() As String
        Get
            Return Estado_Usuario
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Estado_Usuario = value
        End Set
    End Property
    'Email de Usuario
    Private Email_Usuario As String
    Public Property obtenerEmail() As String
        Get
            Return Email_Usuario
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Email_Usuario = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class frmLogin

    Private DatosUsuario As New sesionUsuario

    Private Sub btnIngresar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnIngresar.Click
        ConexionSql.Open()
        Dim consultaUsuario As String = "select * from usuarios where documento='" & txtDocumento.Text & "' and contrasena ='" & txtContrasena.Text & "';"
        Dim existeUsuario As New MySqlCommand(consultaUsuario, ConexionSql)
        Dim adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(existeUsuario)
        Dim dt = New DataTable
        Dim leer As MySqlDataReader
        leer = existeUsuario.ExecuteReader
        If leer.HasRows Then
            While leer.Read()
                DatosUsuario.obtenerDocumento = leer.GetInt32(0)
                DatosUsuario.obtenerIdUsuario = leer.GetInt32(2)
                DatosUsuario.obtenerNombre = leer.GetString(3)
                DatosUsuario.obtenerApellido = leer.GetString(4)
                DatosUsuario.obtenerEmail = leer.GetString(9)
                DatosUsuario.obtenerEstado = leer.GetString(11)
            End While
            leer.Dispose()
            If DatosUsuario.obtenerIdUsuario < 5 Then
                txtDocumento.Text = ""
                txtContrasena.Text = ""
                MsgBox("Bienvenido/a   " + DatosUsuario.obtenerNombre + " " + DatosUsuario.obtenerApellido)
                frmPrincipal.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            Else
                DatosUsuario.obtenerIdUsuario = 5
                txtDocumento.Text = ""
                txtContrasena.Text = ""
                MsgBox("Bienvenido/a   " + DatosUsuario.obtenerNombre + " " + DatosUsuario.obtenerApellido)
                frmClientes.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Documento y/o Contraseña Incorrectos")
            txtDocumento.Text = ""
            txtContrasena.Text = ""
            txtDocumento.Focus()
        End If

        ConexionSql.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Este es el formulario Principal (es una prueba que estoy haciendo a ver si funciona, si no me tendré que quedar con la antigua versión del proyecto u.u )

```
Public Class frmPrincipal
Private sesionUsuario As New sesionUsuario
Public DatosUsuario As New sesionUsuario

Private Sub frmPrincipal_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblnombre.Text = "hola" + sesionUsuario.obtenerNombre + " " + sesionUsuario.obtenerApellido
End Sub
```

End Class

Necesito ayuda. La verdad es que no se si lo estoy haciendo bien o no. Ya me queda poco tiempo y bueh, entra la desesperación :V

Desde ya muchas gracias.

**EDITO: Siguiente problema deribado... **

Tengo el Form principal el cual traigo los datos, pero cuando quiero abrir en un panel (dentro del mismo form) me surge el siguiente problema
En dim **frmCargado** me da error 
"No se ha especificado ningún argumento para el parámentro 'DatosUsuario' de 'Public Sub New(DatosUsuario As sesionUsuario)' "

Boton para traer el frmTecnicos dentro de un panel en frmPrincipal

```
Private Sub btnTecnicos_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTecnicos.CheckedChanged
    'TECNICOS
    If Me.PContenedorForm.Controls.Count > 0 Then
        Me.PContenedorForm.Controls.RemoveAt(0)
    End If
    Dim frmCargado As New frmTecnicos()
    frmCargado.TopLevel = False
    frmCargado.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    frmCargado.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Me.PContenedorForm.Controls.Add(frmCargado)
    Me.PContenedorForm.Tag = frmCargado
    frmCargado = New frmTecnicos(DatosUsuario)
    frmCargado.Show(DatosUsuario)
End Sub
```

frmTecnicos:

```
'Constructor 
Public Sub New(ByVal DatosUsuario As sesionUsuario)
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.DatosUsuario = DatosUsuario
    If DatosUsuario.obtenerIdUsuario = 1 Then
        txtDescripcionAdministrativo.Enabled = True
        txtDiagnostico.Enabled = True
    Else
        If DatosUsuario.obtenerIdUsuario = 2 Then
            txtDescripcionAdministrativo.Enabled = True
            txtDiagnostico.Enabled = False
        Else
            If DatosUsuario.obtenerIdUsuario = 3 Then
                txtDescripcionAdministrativo.Enabled = False
                txtDiagnostico.Enabled = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A priori, tu código se ve correcto. Lo único que te faltaría sería enviar la instancia de `sesionUsuario` que estas completando al formulario principal.

Una forma sería declarar una variable pública en tu `frmPrincipal` de tipo `sesionUsuario`:

```
Public DatosUsuario As sesionUsuario
```

Y al crear el formulario, pasar la información:

```
frmPrincipal.DatosUsuario= DatosUsuario
frmPrincipal.Show()
```

Y hacer lo mismo con el `frmClientes`.

---

Otra opción es que lo pases en el constructor de los formularios:

En el `frmPrincipal`, creas un nuevo constructor:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal DatosUsuario As sesionUsuario)
    InitializeComponent() 
    Me.DatosUsuario = DatosUsuario
    lblnombre.Text = "hola" + DatosUsuario.obtenerNombre + " " + DatosUsuario.obtenerApellido
End Sub
```

En el Form de Login, debes crear el formulario principal cuando ya tienes los datos de login cargados:

Dim frmPrincipal as FormPrincipal ' sin new
   ....
   ...
   frmPrincipal = New FormPrincipal(DatosUsuario)
   frmPrincipal.Show()
   Me.Hide()

De esta manera, pasas los datos a `frmPrincipal` en el momento en el que lo estas creando.

Comment: Hola Pikoh, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder. Lo probé tu consejo y sigue sin traer los datos. (Edito la pregunta agregando el frmPrincipal)

Comment: @GerMarquez no te salen los datos porque lo estás probando en el Form_load, ahi todavía no le has pasado los datos, lo haces despues. Si quieres tenerlos disponibles en ese momento (aunque no creo que sea necesario) puedes hacer un constructor que reciba como parametro una variable de tipo `sesionUsuario` y la meta en tu variable `DatosUsuario`

Comment: @GerMarquez Si quieres probar si funciona lo que tienes, añade un boton en el frmPrincipal y prueba a mostrar los datos ahi, veras como si les tienes

Comment: Muchas gracias! Con el ejemplo del botón click event apareció el dato nombre. El asunto ahora sería si quiero ponerlo en un label. Tipo que muestre quien está conectado y su rango

Comment: @GerMarquez como digo, en ese caso lo mejor es que lo hagas en el constructor del formulario.Crea un constructor personalizado, y creas el formulario cuando ya tengas los datos de login pasandole la informacion en el constructor

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda che, no se si es ya la hora (5:46) o que, pero no lo estoy logrando lo del constructor. Sin embargo tu respuesta me sirvió, al menos ya se que se están guardando los datos, a la prueba está tu sugerencia del boton.
De nuevo mil gracias che!

Comment: @GerMarquez he editado la respuesta para darte una idea de como debes hacerlo usando un constructor personalizado. Espero que te sirva

Comment: Muchisimas gracias che, funcionó! Me queda una banda de trabajo aún (mucho :p ), pero me diste una mano gigantesca. Estaba realmente estancado ya.
De verdad che, infinidad de gracias. Saludos desde Uruguay.

Comment: Buenas, disculpa que te moleste de nuevo. Ahora con la solucion que me diste, tengo otro problema. Quiero abrir un form en un panel en el form principal y no me esta dejando. Edito Arriba

Comment: @GerMarquez en lugar de editar esta pregunta, es mucho mejor que formules otra nueva. Puedes poner un enlace a esta como referencia si quieres.